# Compose gradle community plugins requiring a version in a binary plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a binary plugin that's pushed as an artifact to a remote repository to be re-used.  One of the things I want to accomplish with this plugin is to compose a set of additional plugins that should always be present.  When composing official gradle plugins like the java plugin, that works fine.  But I can't find the strategy for composing a community plugin requiring a version that would use this syntax in a build.gradle.kts file:

```kotlin
  plugins {
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "6.1.0"
}
```

All of the APIs I'm discovering in the gradle plugin library makes no reference of specifying a version, which makes me think I need to configure it elsewhere, like how a build can specify defaults in the `pluginManagement` block in settings.gradle.

This is a distilled version of how I'm trying to apply this.

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        // This works OK
        target.plugins.apply("java")

        // This is a community plugin, so it requires a version be set and fails
        target.plugins.apply("com.diffplug.spotless")
    }
}
```

Is there an API I'm missing?  Or am I approaching this from the wrong direction?

Comment: Does this section of the plugin-development documentation help? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#reacting_to_plugins

Comment: If not - then I think you need to add the Spotless plugin as an `api(...)` dependency (not in the `plugins{}` block!) of the `build.gradle.kts` (using the _Maven coordinates_, not the Gradle plugin ID), for the project that builds your customised plugin.

Comment: This is interesting, but it sounds like this is to react to a plugin only if it's defined, which isn't my goal.  In my case, infrastructure that these projects need to integrate with will require them, and so they are actually required for any project that chooses to apply this plugin.

Comment: @aSemy Can you elaborate a bit?  That sounds like it might be the way to go if I can define it in the plugin's own build.gradle file and specify a version there.  Does that then mean that instead of using the plugin ID, I'd use the Class<T> version of the apply method with it now in my classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by following aSemy's advice in a comment.  I stopped trying to declare community plugins by ID and switched to applying the class of the plugin, after adding it to my plugin's classpath.

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
dependencies {
    api("com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.3.0")
}
```

Plugin class:

```kotlin
import com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.SpotlessPlugin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.plugins.apply("java")
        target.plugins.apply(SpotlessPlugin::class.java)
    }
}
```